# Node.js working with git and a simple JSON database

Tags: node.js, json, database, git, gitignore

I have a small server app with a JSON database. All the data is saved in `data/`. My app is on Heroku, so I use git to update the changes I do on the app. I also added `data/` in the `.gitignore` file, but whenever I commit something, it also wipes down everything in the `data/` folder.

So, how am I supposed to work with a JSON database and Git?

Edit: I don't have any data in local, all the data is handled with fs on the server. So I don't have a `data/` folder when I commit locally, but there is one on the server.

Comment: did you track the data folder at some point?

Comment: File systems on hosted platforms like Heroku are ephemeral, they aren't designed for persistence between instances of the app. See e.g. https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted. Use an external volume service or an actual database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding `data/` to `.gitignore` you're effectively telling git not to send these files. If you want to keep them just remove `data/` from `.gitignore`

Comment: There is no ```data/```folder locally, just edited.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe might have the correct answer to that. He states that Heroku file system is ephemeral (I think your files will last aproximately 24 hours). Check - https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted